# Python argparse: passing single argument with no param name

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like one of my command-line parameters to be available as default if it's passed as a single parameter.

For example:

```
parser.add_argument('--fonts-install',
                    help='Number of fonts to install.'
                    dest='fonts_install',
                    required=False,
                    default=0)
```

Should have the same effect when calling:

```
fonts.py --fonts-install 5
```

or

```
fonts.py 5
```

However, should report an error when trying to use default with other parameters:

```
# this is an error!
fonts.py 5 --verbose
```

Comment: have you used `sys.argv` ?

Comment: Sure, it gives an error when argparge catches unrecognized argument

Comment: Add a '-f' short option string to that argument, and save yourself some programming trouble.  'fonts.py -f5' isn't much more work to type.

Comment: The script is long time widely used in Continuous Integration. This option is for backward compatibility, requirements include not to break it. Problem is already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented as a positional argument, and added post-check:

```
parser.add_argument(dest='fonts_install', metavar='N', 
    type=int, nargs='?', help='Fonts install', default=-1)

# And check compatibility with other arguments
```